# Vimeo API on .net core upload video

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, vimeo-api

I'm using .net core angular template on my vs2017. I want to record videos, and post them to Vimeo using VimeoAPI. When I try to upload a video I get an error "fs_module.stat is not a function" in "filestreamer.js" file inside Vimeo module.  How can I fix the error, what am I doing wrong?

```
 uploadVideo() {

    const lib = new Vimeo(this.ci, this.cs, this.at);
    console.log(lib);
    const fakeAddress: any = 'C:\\test.webm';

    lib.streamingUpload(fakeAddress,  function (error: any, body: any, status_code: any, headers:any) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }

    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    lib.request(headers.location, function (error: any, body: any, status_code: any, headers: any) {
        console.log(body);
    });
    }, function (upload_size: any, file_size: any) {
        console.log('You have uploaded ' + Math.round((upload_size / file_size) * 100) + '% of the video');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this I am using following .net core api to upload video on vimeo

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadVideos([FromForm] IFormFile videoFile)
    {
        string tagName = "tagName";            

        //var files = Request.Form.Files;
        //IFormFile file = files[0];
        string uploadStatus = "";
        var getVideo = new Video();
        try
        {
            if (videoFile != null)
            {
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                VimeoClient vimeoClient = new VimeoClient(accessToken);
                var authcheck = await vimeoClient.GetAccountInformationAsync();

                if (authcheck.Name != null)
                {
                    IUploadRequest uploadRequest = new UploadRequest();
                    //Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream();
                    //using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    //{
                    //    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    //    memoryStream.ToArray();
                    //}
                    BinaryContent binaryContent = new BinaryContent(obj.videoFile.OpenReadStream(), obj.videoFile.ContentType);
                    int chunkSize = 0;
                    int contentLength = Convert.ToInt32(obj.videoFile.Length);
                    int temp1 = contentLength / 1024;
                    binaryContent.OriginalFileName = "Test Name";
                    if (temp1 > 1)
                    {
                        chunkSize = temp1 / 1024;
                        if (chunkSize == 0)
                        {
                            chunkSize = 1048576;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (chunkSize > 10)
                            {
                                chunkSize = chunkSize / 10;
                            }
                            chunkSize = chunkSize * 1048576;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chunkSize = 1048576;
                    }
                    var checkChunk = chunkSize;
                    var status = "uploading";
                    uploadRequest = await vimeoClient.UploadEntireFileAsync(binaryContent, chunkSize, null);
                    var _tag =  tagName;
                    var tagVideo = await vimeoClient.AddVideoTagAsync(uploadRequest.ClipId.GetValueOrDefault(), _tag);
                    while (status != "available")
                    {
                        getVideo = await vimeoClient.GetVideoAsync(long.Parse(uploadRequest.ClipId.Value.ToString()));
                        status = getVideo.Status;
                    }
                    uploadStatus = String.Concat("file Uploaded ", getVideo.Files[0].LinkSecure);
                }
            }
            return Ok(new { status = uploadStatus, video = getVideo });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```